# How to enable imap features in MacOs Catalina

Tags: php, macos-catalina

I'm trying to use PHP imap features on MacOS Catalina, but i'm always getting this error when calling 'imap_open' :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imap_open()

I know i need to enable the imap extension, and i did it on /etc/php.ini.default :

```
extension=imap
```

Restarted Apache but even so, i keep getting the same error. What i'm doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check that the imap extension was actually installed

Comment: Actually i just enabled it on php.ini. Should i do something else ?

Comment: does that .so exist in the ext folder?

Comment: Actually it is not, i checked with php -m... I'll look for instructions to install it